# public_html on a subdomain (in order to make HTTPS work)

Tags: migration, ssl-certificate

I'm gonna try to make this comprehensible. My web hotel was integrated into another. The consequence was many problems including this specific one: If I write https://example.com it returns the results. If I write https://subdomain.example.com it returns a

"Your connection is not private. Attackers might be trying to steal your information from...." followed by "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID".

I noticed the following: After the migration to their new servers, they put the contents of https://example.com into a public_html folder. But the subdomains' contents are still inside a folder called subdomain.example.com without a public_html inside. I have a feeling this has to do with the error message I receive when trying to see the page with HTTPS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just managed it from their control panel. There was no way I could do it from inside the file manager itself, by modifinying files and folders.